# how to return the form validation back in cakePHP

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, web

i need to return the form validation because i lost it after submitting

i'm on News/view/30 ---view a report details----
in that page we have add comment Form :

```
        <h2>Add comment</h2>
        <?php
        echo $this->Form->create("Comment", array(
                    'url' => array('controller' => 'Comments', 'action' => 'add')
                ));
        echo $this->Form->label("name");
        echo $this->Form->input("name", array("label" => false, "class" => "textfield"));
        echo $this->Form->label("email");
        echo $this->Form->input("email", array("label" => false, "class" => "textfield"));
        echo $this->Form->label("text");
        echo $this->Form->textarea("text", array("label" => false));
        echo $this->Form->input("object_id", array("type" => "hidden", "value" => $data['News']['id']));
        echo $this->Form->input("type", array("type" => "hidden", "value" => "news"));
        echo $this->Html->Link("Add Comment", "#", array("class" => "add_button", "onclick" => "$('#CommentViewForm').submit()"));
        echo $this->Form->end();
        ?>
```

the form is submiting on Comment controller :

in comment/add :

```
        $isSuccess = $this->Comment->save($this->request->data);
        if ($isSuccess) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('your Comments has been added successfully and pending admin aproval.thanks ', 'default', array(), 'good');
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Failed to add your comment: <br/>Fill all the required fileds <br/>type correct Email', 'default', array(), 'bad');
        }
         $this->redirect(array("controller" => "News", "action" => "view", $id));
```

i did some validation rules on name,email and the comment itself
when there are errors in user inputs return to add Comment Form but didnt show the errors as usual

i hope you understand me very well, and i wait your help
thank alot

Answer (score 0):

just try to add `'error'=>true` to each input form helper
like `echo $this->Form->input("name", array("label" => false, "class" => "textfield", 'error'=>true));`

See if this work .

Comment: thanks all but . there is no any view to Comments/add so if no redirect i will get missing view error ?

Comment: try to echo this `$this->request->data` after you getting error just before redirecting function.
ie. `print_r($this->request->data); exit;`
You might get something useful.

Answer (score 0):

You should first bake some code, if you didnt' work with CakePHP for that long.
Then you would learn that you should not redirect if the form does not validate:

```
if ($this->Comment->save($this->request->data)) {
    $this->Session->setFlash('your Comments has been added successfully and pending admin aproval.thanks ', 'default', array(), 'good');
    $this->redirect(array("controller" => "News", "action" => "view", $id));
} else {
    $this->Session->setFlash('Failed to add your comment: <br/>Fill all the required fileds <br/>type correct Email', 'default', array(), 'bad');
    // DO NOT redirect
}
```

The bake templates will bake your controller code this way. This asserts a clean and transparent way of dealing with forms.

Comment: hanks all but . there is no any view to Comments/add so if no redirect i will get missing view error ?

Comment: why dont you have a view? if you add it in your "view" action, you need to post to your "view" and also handle the saving part in your "view" action. always try to post to itself. this makes form handling the easiest. otherwise you would need to work with session and other tricks to persist the form, which can be quite annoying and difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Won't your redirect stop you seeing your validation errors? You're redirecting the user to a new page (the view page) even if there are errors, so they'll never see any validation error messages.

Trying commenting out this line:

```
//$this->redirect(array("controller" => "News", "action" => "view", $id));
```

or making it conditional on $isSuccess being true.

**UPDATE**
Re: your comment - the thing is, if you redirect away from the page with the form on, you will not (easily) be able to display you validation error messages. The easiest thing would be to have your form submit to its own action - by the sound of it you're submitting it to an action in another controller.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to handle the form->save in the view action on the News controller, then as others have said, don't redirect away from the page if it fails validation.

If you redirect you'll still see the validation message atleast once (from the session Flash) but you'll lose the filled in form data.

Easiest solution is move the save to your News->view method and if your News and Comment models are associated just use the traversal available to save the Comment there:

```
$isSuccess = $this->News->Comment->save($this->request->data);
```